# How to open two different instances of LaTeX?

Tags: texmaker

Every time I open a new `.tex` file, the old one is closed. I want to copy content from one file and paste it into another keeping both the files open. How could I do that using TexMaker?

Comment: This has nothing to do with instances of LaTeX, but with the way TexMaker displays files. There should be a small menu containing the name of the current file showing just above the contents of the file. There you should be able to choose between all files that are currently open in TexMaker.

Comment: That was simple and very helpful.